# Left outer join with a table of only foreign keys using Linq in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to do a left outer join on two tables, Table A and Table B. But Table B is the junction column between TableA and Table C with only two columns both are foreign keys. One of the column is a primary key of Table A and the other is foreign key of table C.

How do I outer join the tables as Entity Framework does not create an object called TableB? I am using a database-first approach.

```
from a in db.tableA
join b in (no Table B object) on a.Id equals b.userId into group1
from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { id = g1.Id, userId = g1.userId }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811834/table-with-2-foreign-keys-entity-framework) is a different question but this question also has similar issues in terms of not being able to create an object for the table with two foreign keys.

Comment: What you mean by **I cannot navigate to the Table B in Entity Framework?** ? What is your expected output and what is your problem ?

Comment: It's a table with only foreign keys. S I cannot do db.tableB as  I do with db.TableA as EF do not create table B object.

Comment: Are you doing code first ?

Comment: @Shyju Data First. Please check my latest edit if it helps explain my issue better.

Comment: The real question is "how do you define your entities?"

Comment: If `Table B` is just the connecting table for the many-to-many relationship between `Table A` and `Table C`, then you should consider joining `A` and `C` as far as entity framework is concerned.

Comment: @grek40 How do I join A and C when there is no common key between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have a many-to-many relationship between elements from table A and elements from table B: Every A has zero or more Bs, and every B belongs to zero or more As.

(here: As is the plural of an A, Bs is the plural of a B)

You are right, in a relational database a many-to-many relationship is implemented using a third table, quite often called the junction table.

And you are right, if you properly design your class A and class B for a many-to-many relationship in entity framework, you don't have access to the junction table.

**Luckily you won't need the junction table!**

If you've setup your classes correctly for an [entity framework many-to-many relation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), they will be as follows

```
class A
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every A has zero or more Bs:
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs {get; set;}

    ... //  other properties
}
class B
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every B belongs to zero or more As:
    public virtual ICollection<A> As {get; set;}

    ... //  other properties
}
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As {get; set;}
    public DbSet<B> Bs {get; set;}
}
```

This is enough to tell entity framework that you want to design a many-to-many relationship between As and Bs.

Although you don't mention the junction table, entity framework knows that a junction table is needed and create it for you.

You probably want to do your left outer join on your table with A elements and your table with B elements because you want something like:

> Give me all elements from table A that have ... with all their Bs which have ...

If you'd be using SQL, then you would do a left outer join of table A with the junction table, and some kind of join with table B. After that you'd do the desired WHERE to get your result.

When using entity framework you won't need the junction table:

```
var result = myDbContext.As
    .Where(a => <predicate with the As you want in the result>)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        ... // properties from A that you want

        Bs = a.Bs.Where(b => <predicate with the Bs from A you want>)
    }
```

Because you use the Bs from every A, entity framework will know that joins must be done with the junction table. Because A might haver zero Bs, entity framework will use a left outer join.

Comment: I would suspect the expected outcome to be multiple lines of `A` if more than one `B` is related to the same `A`

Comment: Why would you want that if in fact you'd really want every matching A with all his matching Bs? I think you are still thinking in SQL statements instead of thinking in acquiring the resulting collection that would solve your problem. Do you really want an A with one of his Bs and the same A with another of his Bs and again the same A with yet another of his Bs etc? It is a deficiency of relational databases that you'd come to think of this, while usually you want a customer with all his orders that match something. If you really want this, consider using `Enumerable.SelectMany`.

Comment: Well unfortunately the question doesn't contain a real goal but only specifies the desire to do a *left outer join*, so welcome to the world of XY problems and SQL. Ofcourse you are right that the real problem is probably better solved in a different way.

Comment: When I switched from SQL to entity framework I met the same problems, until someone told me: stop thinking in joins and SQL limitations, think in collections you want to gather. After I started doing this I seldom need a join, because to make two table joinable (using foreign keys), I had to have classes have collections of other classes. I can always use the ICollection whenever I would have joined on foreign key. Internally this will be translated to a SQL join